# cannot receive extra data from parse push notification on android

Tags: javascript, java, android, json, parse-platform

I use the following cloud code to send parse notifications to android devices:

```
Parse.Cloud.define('SendNot', function(request, response)
{
    var query = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
    query.equalTo('channels', 'Customer');

    Parse.Push.send
    ({
        where: query ,
        data: 
        {
            alert: "Hai customers",
            flag: "true"
        }
    }, 
    { 
        useMasterKey : true,
        success: function() 
        {
            response.success("true");
        },
        error: function(error) 
        {
            response.error("error");
        }
    });
});
```

I want to get the data stored in "flag" field. I use the following code to receive notification:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent)
{
    System.out.println("Received Notification");
    jsonString = intent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data");
    try {
        json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
        System.out.println(json.getString("flag") + " Notification content");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

I am able to receive the notifications. But, I can't get the value of "flag". It shows the following Exception:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int 
java.lang.String.length()' on a null object reference
                    03-11 10:56:48.170 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextCleanInternal(JSONTokener.java:116)
                    03-11 10:56:48.170 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONTokener.nextValue(JSONTokener.java:94)
                    03-11 10:56:48.170 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:156)
                    03-11 10:56:48.170 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at org.json.JSONObject.<init>(JSONObject.java:173)
                    03-11 10:56:48.170 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at com.hashcoder.eegoomain.MyBroadcastReceiver.onReceive(MyBroadcastReceiver.java:31)
                    03-11 10:56:48.170 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2732)
                    03-11 10:56:48.170 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1800(ActivityThread.java:153)
                    03-11 10:56:48.170 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1428)
                    03-11 10:56:48.171 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                    03-11 10:56:48.171 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                    03-11 10:56:48.171 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5441)
                    03-11 10:56:48.171 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                    03-11 10:56:48.171 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:738)
                    03-11 10:56:48.171 22214-22214/com.hashcoder.eegoomain W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:628)
```

Whats wrong with the code?

Comment: from where did you call the function 'onReceive'?

Comment: I call it from a class called MyBroadcastReceiver which extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver. I also added this class to manifest as a receiver like this: `<receiver
            android:name=".MyBroadcastReceiver"
            android:permission="com.google.android.c2dm.permission.SEND">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.android.c2dm.intent.RECEIVE"/>
                <category android:name="com.hashcoder.eegoomain"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create another class which extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver and call onPushReceive function on that class.

```
    public class ClassName extends ParsePushBroadcastReceiver
    {
        String jsonString;
        JSONObject json;`

        protected void onPushReceive(Context mContext, Intent mintent)
        {
            jsonString = mintent.getExtras().getString("com.parse.Data");
            try {
                json = new JSONObject(jsonString);
                System.out.println(json.getString("flag") + " Notification content");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }                                                                                                 
    }
```

And add this class to the manifest file as a receiver like this:

```
<receiver
        android:name=".ClassName"
        android:exported="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.RECEIVE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.DELETE" />
            <action android:name="com.parse.push.intent.OPEN" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```